# How to set the dependencies of a service from its provider in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.provider('routeResolver', ['$q','$rootScope',function($q, $rootScope)
    {        
        console.log( $q, $rootScope );
        this.$get = function()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }]

);
```

However, this gives the error: `Unknown Provider $q`

So I changed the code to the following:

```
myApp.provider('routeResolver', ['$qProvider','$rootScopeProvider',function($q, $rootScope)
    {        
        console.log( $q.defer() );
        console.log( $rootScope );
        this.$get = function()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }]
);
```

This however gives the error of `uknown function.`. Even doing:

```
console.log( $q.$get().defer() );
```

doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
this.$get = function()
  {
    return this;
  }
```

try this:

```
return {
  // object being returned has to implement $get method
  $get: function() {
    // you should be able to use $q and $rootScope here
    return this;
  }
};
```

Besides `$get`, it should be possible to have other methods which can also access all the injected services:

```
return {
  // object being returned has to implement $get method
  $get: function() {
    // you should be able to use $q and $rootScope here
    return this;
  },
  // you can also have more methods here
  someOtherMethod: function() {
    // you should be able to use $q and $rootScope here as well
    // for example:
    $rootScope.$apply();
  }
};
```

That is assuming you injected `$q` and `$rootScope` into the constructor function (regardless of whether you're using array notation or not).

This is what I infer from [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide) and [here](http://iffycan.blogspot.com/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html)

Comment: How would I access `$q` and `$rootScope` from the new `$get` method?

Comment: If you injected them as `$q` and `$rootScope`, then exactly like you normally would anywhere else (referring to '$q' and '$rootScope'). But it needs to be done within the `$get` function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'how i normally would anywhere else'.. I'm a bit new to angular. Could you add a little code showing how I would access `$q` and `$rootScope` from the new `$get`? I'd like it to be done with the array method if possible so minification won't be an issue

Comment: I'm not sure myself, but I'll update my example with some thoughts.

Comment: Btw, array notation is treated the same as passing a function, with the benefits you mentioned. That shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it but get the same `q.defer is not a function` error. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/6GhpW/ .

Comment: Perhaps how this guy's doing it might be of some help? Its beyond my understanding though. http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx . Have a look at its code for the `routeResolver` service.

Comment: The `$q` which is passed into the provider seems to be a `$qProvider` rather than a regular `$q`. It might be because my `routeResolver` provider is being called for `myApp.config()` and the documentation says only providers and not actual instances are allowed for that method.

Comment: So, you may inject either `$q` (a service) or `$qProvider` (a provider) into your providers, but the only things that are available to you at the config stage are `providers` and `constants`. `Services`, `factories` and `values` are available only at runtime. Angular makes this clear separation of the configuration stage and the runtime stage. Also a side-note: `service`, `factory`, `constant` and `value` are all just higher-level variations of `provider`. I hope this helps @ClickUpvote

Comment: So if you need to use it in `config`, you can only inject `$qProvider`, and if you need `$q`, I'm not sure, but `$qProvider.$get()` might work for that.